# capture ip packets when the gateway is not the ISP router

Tags: linux, networking, ip

In my home network I have the following topology

```
          Internet
              |
     wifi     |
C ----------- A ---------- B
```

where

- A (static IP 192.168.0.254) is the router/AP given by my ISP.
- B (static IP 192.168.0.1) is a linux machine working as local DNS and DHCP server (running dnsmasq)
- C is any client connecting to the AP and configured by DHCP.

For now, the default gateway supplied by B (as DHCP server) is just A.

Then, suppose I want to capture in B all traffic coming from any client C. Here's what I did on B:

1. activate IP forwarding with

   ```
   # sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1"
   ```
2. supply B as gateway. Of course, B itself uses A as its own gateway
3. run tcpdump on B to see what's going on

On a client C, I start any request, e.g.

```
$ traceroute www.google.com
```

Now, I expect that traffic originating from C is routed to B, then to A and finally to the internet.

**What works.** C is able to reach the internet

**What does not work.** Except for the first request, it seems that B is completely bypassed: tcpdump does not show anything; the address of B doesn't show up in the traceroute output. Still, I'm sure that reroute takes place because C is cut out from internet if I disable IP forwarding on B.

If some sort of short-curcuit is happening, how can I avoid it?

**Disclaimer**: I know that changing the network topology could solve the "capture all traffic" problem (e.g. by port mirroring etc.), but I really want to understand what's going on with my setup and how to fix that without changing topology.

Comment: Assuming you wanted to say "C uses B as gateway, while B uses A as gateway", then this will only work if A bridges WLAN and LAN, because otherwise C and B are not in the same segment. So you need to get into the A via `ssh` or otherwise, and look and possible change what A does. If A just forwards packets from C to the internet, there's nothing you can do unless you can change the way A works (e.g. by flashing it with OpenWRT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need host B to do NAT translations so that A does not see the same packet again. Instead B should send out packets through A as if they originated from B. To achieve that you add an `iptables` rule as follows:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ip-of-C -j MASQUERADE
```

By that rule, all packets out from B will be rewritten to be as if sourced from B, but keeping a table of back translations, so that associated responses can be back-translated and sent to C.

Note the `-s ...` part which limits the rule to only apply to packets sourced from C (or it could be set as the local LAN), and e.g., not the response packets.

EDIT (taking @theuncle's comment into account): The explanation as to why it doesn't work without NAT would be, that host B realizes the packet comes in and goes out unaltered on the same interface, so it can improve networking by telling C to talk directly with A for the traffic concerned.

Comment: 1) This is not the problem, the problem is that packets from A never reach B. So you can set up NAT on B until you are blue in the face, if there are no packets from A to NAT on B, it won't help. 2) If you control A, you don't need B to do NAT. If you don't control A, you won't be able to fix it.

Comment: @ralph Thanks, this is helpful and solves my problem. Meantime, I also discovered that my setup, even without the iptables rule you gave, half-works until machine B sends an ICMP Redirect Host message to C.